# Se promener, (se) balader

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

Le verbe "balader" peut-il être utilisé dans le même sens que "se promener" ? D'après le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/balader) je comprends que oui, en plus on peut l'employer à la place de "se balader", par exemple: "on aime bien balader" est aussi correct que "on aime bien se balader".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux verbes ne s'emploient pas toujours de la même façon.

**Emploi pronominal:**
On peut dire :
« J'aime bien me promener » et « j'aime bien me balader », les deux sont corrects, *se balader* est considéré comme plus familier.

**Emploi transitif :**
« Je promène mes chiens ».
« Je promène mes enfants ou je les balade ».
Personnellement je ne balade que des personnes, je promène les chiens et trimbale les choses... mais je reconnais que certains baladent parfois des objets et des chiens, bien que cet emploi soit plus rare.

**Emploi intransitif:**
*Balader* ne s'emploie plus de façon intransitive de nos jours<sup>*</sup> (donc en ça je ne suis pas d'accord avec le wiktionnaire. Donc je ne dirais pas et « on aime bien balader ».

L'emploi intransitif de *promener* est considéré comme vieilli et régional  (*Dictionnaire historique en langue française* - sld Alain Rey). En effet j'ai entendu « je vais promener » dans le midi, mais pas au nord de la Loire.

---

<sup>*</sup> Alors qu'à l'origine il ne s'employait que de façon intransitive. Jusqu'au XVI<sup>e</sup>siècle balader voulait dire chanter des ballades en se déplaçant de ville en ville (ce que faisaient souvent les mendiants). Et de là on est passé au sens de marcher sans but.

Comment: « Je vais promener » ne me gène pas, mais dans tout autre contexte un emploi intransitif me semble bizarre.  Je ne me souviens pas si c'est quelque chose que j'ai acquis ici (dans le midi d'où ma femme est originaire et où je vis depuis plus de quinze ans) ou si c'est en usage aussi en Belgique (d'où je suis originaire).

Comment: Pour moi, une balade a une connotation d'etre plus longue ou plus difficile qu'une promenade, et se balader est generalemment plus que se promener.  On parle d'une "promenade de dimanche" et "se promener en ville" (plus leger) vs "se balader en montagne" (plus consequent). N'y a-t-il pas cette difference aussi?

Answer (score 1):

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balader) donne les définitions suivantes :

> A.− Emploi trans. Promener sans but déterminé quelque chose ou
>   quelqu'un : 
>   1. Et les riches, qui s'arc-boutent pour ne pas payer la pension à leur divorcée, et foutent leur fils unique interne, mais baladent
>   chaque jour au bois le cocker, non qu'il en ait envie, mais parce
>   qu'il coûte deux mille francs. Montherlant, Les Lépreuses,1939, p.
>   1512.
>   2. ... c'est insensé les libertés qu'on prend avec des personnages de roman; on les transporte d'un siècle à l'autre, on les balade d'un
>   pays dans un autre, on colle le présent de celui-ci avec le passé de
>   celui-là, en y insérant des fantasmes personnels... S. de Beauvoir,
>   Les Mandarins,1954, p. 120.
>   − P. ext. Emporter avec soi, promener : 
>   3. C'est une femme de chambre, (...) elle a l'accent bordelais et elle tient en ses bras l'appareil téléphonique qu'elle balade au bout du
>   fil. S. Guitry, Le Veilleur de nuit,1911, I, p. 4.
>   4. Je ramenais ce que je trouvais. C'était que juste suffisant. Je baladais plus ma collection. Ça m'aurait fait plutôt virer. Céline,
>   Mort à crédit,1936, p. 210.
>   − Fam. Envoyer balader qqn.Envoyer
>   promener, repousser violemment, rabrouer quelqu'un : 
>   5. − À la Sierra j'ai dit à une milicienne qu'elle avait de beaux chevaux; je lui ai demandé de m'en donner un, elle m'a envoyé balader.
>   Votre avarice est égale à la sienne. Malraux, L'Espoir,1937, p. 849.
>   B.− Emploi pronom. 
>   1. [En parlant de pers.] Se promener, flâner : 
>   6. Il y avait pourtant derrière eux beaucoup plus de chameaux que de citoyens français, mais ils ne servaient qu'à porter des tentes, des
>   petits canons, des conserves, des cartouches, et on les faisait
>   marcher très lentement. L'armée se baladait en trois colonnes, à cause
>   d'un plan magnifique tracé d'avance à Paris, .... Mille, Barnavaux et
>   quelques femmes...,1908, p. 137.
>   7. C'est une bibliothèque en plein air [des bouquinistes]. Pierre Reverdy aurait dû y venir pour lutter contre son vertige. Je ne l'y ai
>   jamais rencontré. On peut lire, flâner, se balader, rêvasser, ...
>   Cendrars, Bourlinguer,1948, p. 325.
>   2. P. ext. [En parlant d'animaux ou de choses] Circuler, se déplacer sans cesse : 
>   8. De grosses mouches entrent faire un tour, (...) Des petites se baladent un peu partout. Queneau, Pierrot mon ami,1942, p. 48.
>   9. Troisième pièce : établissement de la fiche dactyloscopique. Le rouleau encreur se balade inlassablement sur la plaque de cuivre. H.
>   Bazin, La Tête contre les murs,1949, p. 148.
>   10. ... il fait un temps immobile, ni mauvais ni bon. Ce qu'on en voit donne à peu près ceci : le fond de la vallée est noir comme de
>   l'encre; à nos hauteurs se balade une foule de brumes blanches comme
>   du lait de chaux. Giono, Les Grands chemins,1951, p. 147. 
> PRONONC. :
>   [balade].

Comment: Plutôt que de tout citer, tu devrais sélectionner ce qui est applicable à la question. Voire simplement résumer.